# Puzzle #2: Prosecutor's Pathway

Tags: calculation-puzzle

This one prosecutor has a very busy schedule. However, although his business can get busy, he is a lawyer faithful to his job, which is why he spends some weekend time at his private law firm.

Since his weekends don't follow a set schedule, he usually just rounds the amount of time to the nearest quarter hour for his activities. He reads for 45 minutes, takes about 1 hour and 30 minutes to eat when all 3 meals are combined, spends 1 hour for personal grooming, and sleeps for about 10 hours. In the summer, he swims in his pool for 1 hour and 15 minutes, and lays on his hammock for about 30 minutes.

One thing that stays the same with every attorney in the town is the meeting times. He goes to his office for about 2 hours for meetings. If casual meetings with one person take 30 minutes and pretrial meetings take 45 minutes, what is the fewest number of clients he can see in this 2 hour time interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the fewest number of clients he can see is:

> Zero, as nobody says that his schedule is full on the weekends as well.

Comment: You're actually correct, but that isn't the reason why

Answer (score 2):

> 3 clients, 2 pretrial and 1 casual. 45+45+30 = 2 hour

Comment: Nope, this is incorrect